# Blacklist for To/CC in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

I have Thunderbird set up to auto-bcc my account for all emails, and disabled the 'Sent' folder.

Unfortunately if I'm in an email threads and *Reply to all* I get double-copied:

- once by *Reply to all*;
- once bt auto-bcc.

Are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: More generic, this might apply to *any* Reply to All, even when not using that Bcc-trick. As you're the sender, why should you be in To or Cc to start with? (And the mail server does not see this is the same message? Odd. If I include myself multiple times, then I only get a single message.)

Comment: Well, I end up twice because I'm in the CC list for instance, and when replying I'm also Bcc-ing myself.

Comment: @Robert, my comment wasn't actually a question towards you, but more like" "why do email clients behave like that". ;-)

Comment: I'd like to blacklist certain *other* people from receiving emails from me.  Mostly people who have left the company but accidentally end up in Reply All lists, etc.  I'd like it to be a setting for each Contact in the address book.  Should I ask a different question for that, or does this cover it?

Comment: @endolith that would be another question I guess

Answer (score 1):

I believe this may be what you're looking for: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/4935

Comment: -1 Links are not answers.  You should explain what the extension does in your answer, don't just link to it.  Also, this extension is for manually removing specific people from a Thunderbird mailing list, which doesn't sound like what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that's brilliant and I'm not sure how I never thought of it or heard of doing it before.

As for the solution.  Obviously there's no built-in way to do it or you'd probably have found it already.  Have you searched the available extensions for anything that would do the trick?  Even if one doesn't exist, I wouldn't think it'd be too terribly hard to write from scratch.

Comment: Nope, found nothing I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

If you're mailing an email list, this is hard to avoid. The mailing list server can't see the bcc: header, so even with servers that do handle the case of not sending you your own messages twice, it won't work.

This has to be handled on the side of the client, but I'm not aware of an extension to do it. Probably something along the lines of "delete duplicate emails"?

Answer (score 0):

This might work: The [Check and Send extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/check-and-send/) will check, before a message is sent, whether a recipient exists in a specific field from a specific address book.

You could create a custom address book that only contains one address, and then configure the extension to automatically remove it if it appears in the **To:** list when you hit Send.  The options are a little confusing, but seem very configurable.

It seems like it will solve my problem of blacklisting obsolete addresses from *Reply All*, also.