# Thunderbird Reply2All mistake when having two addresses

Tags: email, thunderbird

I have a Gmail account and a second email address. The mail from this second address is forwarded to the Gmail address.
I use Thunderbird to read my email, but there's a little problem with the Reply2All feature. See, I have one of the addresses registered as my email address in Thunderbird. If somebody sends me an email on the other address, and I click reply 2 all, it doesn't recognize that address as mine, so it adds it to the recipient list -> I am mailing myself.
Anything I can do to fix this? Some way to let TB recognize both addresses?

Comment: Like a blacklist? http://superuser.com/questions/5676/blacklist-for-to-cc-in-thunderbird

Comment: Yes, that would solve it I guess

Answer (score 1):

If you set up another identity on the account as [detailed here](http://mozilla.gunnars.net/thunderbird_mail_setup.html#multiple-identities) with the alternate e-mail address does that work?

*I can't test this myself at the moment as I don't have Thunderbird installed on this computer.*